# What does this sentence with "but for" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality-in-context

> He would have faced a prison sentence but for mitigating circumstances.

Is it an incomplete sentence?

'Mitigate' meaning-make less severe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might seem like an incomplete sentence if you treat *but* as a conjunction and *for* as the start of a prepositional phrase.

However, when parsing that sentence, you need to treat "but for" as a single unit:

From the webpages of [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/but+for):

> **Idiom:**
>    **but for**
>    Were it not for; except for : *We would have reached the summit but for the weather.*

Therefore, the sentence you have provided in your question is both grammatical and complete.

(You may have been able to figure this out on your own but for that tricky idiom.)